# preg_match problem

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How do I add the character `-` within the preg_match?

`preg_match('#^(\w+/){0,2}\w+\.\w+$#', $string)`

But it must be before the last `.` within the string.  I've tried just about everything I know here.  I know that the `-` needs to be escaped.  So I tried to escape it in various places, but it's not working :(

argggg

Comment: dashes are only special in a character class, eg `[a-z]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your knowlegde that the dash needs to be escaped is incomplete.

```
preg_match('#^(\w+/){0,2}\w+-\.\w+$#', $string)
```

It needs to be escaped in [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), because it has a special meaning there, but it has no special meaning in the rest of the regex, so it needs no escaping here.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete. Post the strings you are trying to match.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it's working, what's the best way to check for this?  If a return == 1?  Would that work?  Does this return how many matches, or does it return 1 for any and all matches?

Comment: It does return 0 for 0 matches, or 1 for "match found". It does not count matches, it stops after the first. Please have a look at the documentation, this can also return FALSE under certain conditions.

Comment: Also, I've only been reading up on PCRE recently, and all instances I see a `\-` so it makes me think that it must need to be escaped.  I don't understand this, arggg.

Comment: No, you see `\-` only in character classes. Look more closely.

Comment: Also, would this work for a `preg_replace` than:  `#^/|/$|[^A-Za-z0-9_.-/]#` or does this 1 need to be escaped?

Comment: It is in a character class, so it needs to be escaped. Seriously, at the very least read the page I linked to in my answer as well as the documentation of the preg_* functions.